# angular-php api not found after minification

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, api

I scaffolded a basic angular-php yeoman app to try it out.

[angular-php](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular-php)

When I run grunt serve it works as expected and pulls some data using rest using `$http.get('/api/features')....`

When I minifiy the project it creates a dist folder which I assumed could be dropped onto a webserver so I dropped it onto XAMPP and browsed to localhost:8000/dist.

The site loads ok but it cannot find the api

```
localhost:8000/api/features not found
```

when I browse to localhost:8000/dist/api/features it returns the json so the api is functioning, so I changed the get url to $http.get('dist/api/features') only this time it says

```
localhost:8000/dist/dist/api/features not found
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops. Seems I forgot a /.

Should have been /dist/api/features